# GraphQL NodeJS Deferred fields

Tags: node.js, graphql

Is it possible to defer field type resolution?

```js
module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "AccountType",
    description: "Represents an Account",
    fields: () => ({
        ownerId: { type: () => (GraphQLID),
            resolve: (parent) => {
                return parent.OwnerId;
            } },
    })
})
```

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: I was thinking in a library or something.. Person borrows [Book] s and they are in turn borrowed by people or [Person]. So Person has Books and Book has People. Circular dependency.

Comment: Okay I get it. But can you explain your question, maybe I could help you

Comment: So I may be trying to do something that there is a better way of doing. Maybe there is a design pattern or something that I'm breaking here. But what I want to do is create this circular dependency. The actual objects don't matter it could be any domain. Book->Person->Book. Or Parent->Has Children->Have Parents literally anything. I may be missing some Javascript concept that allows for late binding or something like that. Or maybe people usually create some intermediate object? Not sure this helps explain what the issue is but hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not see some error with the above code. You just should not place the `GraphQLID` in parentheses.